# Facebook Graph API get likes/reactions

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to fetch some data from **page posts** on Facebook with the Graph API. I'm using Python normally but I try the queries first with the Exploration tool offered by Facebook.

I used the page_id + post_id to get the number of reactions (I would also like to get the count for each different reaction) and likes. But it just returns nothing. I get the data for the shares though. I have the post open on another tab and it has likes and reactions.

Don't know what I'm doing wrong.
[image]

Comment: What kind of post is it - user, page, group …?

Comment: its from a public page

Comment: Don’t think you can get that any more; you would need page admin access.

Comment: Okay, too bad, thank you!